# neutron error "(rule:create_port and rule:create_port:fixed_ips) to be performed"

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I am trying to add multiple fixed IP address to some open stack instances I have running.  I am attempting to do this with the following command:

```
neutron port-create \
 --format shell \
 --fixed-ip subnet_id <subnet id> \
 --fixed-ip subnet_id <subnet id> \
 --name whatever \
 <network id>
```

However running this command results in the following error:

```
Policy doesn't allow (rule:create_port and rule:create_port:fixed_ips) to be performed.
```

If I try to create a port without the `--fixed-ip subnet_id <subnet id>` I can successfully create it.  With the following command:

```
neutron port-create --name whatever <network id>
```

However when I attempt to attach it to an instance I get the following error message:

```
ERROR (BadRequest): The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect. (HTTP 400)
```

I have also tried to attach additionaly IP addresses to my instance with:

```
nova add-fixed-ip <server> <network-id>
```

Which successfully runs, but does not change my instance at all, add additional network interfaces or add additional IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the format for fixed_ip have been 
"--fixed-ip subnet_id=SUBNET" ?

Did you try adding the port using the 'nova interface-attach' command ?